# Python while loop Syntax Error

Tags: python, while-loop

I am learning Python and while working on a simple while loop I get a syntax error but cannot figure out why. Below is my code and the error I get

```
products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3']
quote_items = []
quote = input("What services are you interesting in? (Press X to quit)")
while (quote.upper() != 'X'):
    product_found = products.get(quote)
    if product_found:
        quote_items.append(quote)
    else:
        print("No such product")
    quote = input("Anything Else?")
print(quote_items)
```

I am using NetBeans 8.1 to run these. Below is the error I see after I type in Product 1:

```
What servese are you interesting in? (Press X to quit)Product 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\\NetBeansProjects\\while_loop.py", line 3, in <module>
quote = input("What services are you interesting in? (Press X to quit)")
File "<string>", line 1
Product 1
SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input '1'
```

Comment: Are you running code written for Python 3 on Python 2?

Comment: I think I am running 3. Is there a way to check?

Comment: On a side note, lists do not have any `get` method: `products.get(quote)` will raise an error

Comment: `import sys` `sys.version`

Comment: looks like I am running 2.7.0

Comment: To find out which version just type python.  You will end up in a python shell and the version will be printed

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is the exact code you're running?  According to your posted code the input prompt should be `What services are you interesting in`, but the posted output is `What servese are you interesting in`

Comment: yeah...I misspelled it and corrected on but not the other after I noticed it. Same code.

Comment: It's possible that NetBeans uses a different version of Python than the one you get by just typing `python` at the command line.

Comment: Can you try printing `sys.version` from within the NetBeans script?

Comment: It says 2.7.0 when I do it

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade it to 3.5 for netBean?

Comment: Thanks. I switch to Eclipse and now using Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in *Python 3*

```
products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3']
quote_items = []
quote = input("What services are you interesting in? (Press X to quit)")
while (quote.upper() != 'X'):
    product_found = quote in products
    if product_found:
        quote_items.append(quote)
    else:
        print("No such product")
    quote = input("Anything Else?")
print(quote_items)
```

in *Python 2*

```
products = ['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3']
quote_items = []
quote = raw_input("What services are you interesting in? (Press X to quit)")
while (quote.upper() != 'X'):
    product_found = quote in products
    if product_found:
        quote_items.append(quote)
    else:
        print "No such product"
    quote = raw_input("Anything Else?")
print quote_items
```

this is because lists don't have the attribute '.get()' so you can use

`value in list`
that will return a `True` or `False` value

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Python evaluates `input` as pure python code.

```
quote = raw_input("What services are you interesting in? (Press X to quit)")
```

Comment: Not if he's using Python 3.

Comment: @JohnGordon Apparently he's not.

Comment: @chepner If he really is using Python 2, then I would have expected a different error from the user input of "Product 1".